# The difference between two population means

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, independence

I am trying to answer this question:

```
There is no difference between two population means. From each of these two populations
a sample is selected and then for both samples the means are calculated. 

Consider this:
"since the null hypo is true, a significant result can never be found when we perform
a t-test for independent measures (two-tailed, alpha = 0.05)
```

Can we say that is statement is in/correct, partially correct, or insufficient to answer? I am really unsure of which path to take.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is totally false. Let's do an R simulation.

```
set.seed(2021)
ps <- rep(NA, 1000)
for (i in 1:1000){

    # Simulate data from two identical distributions
    #
    x <- rnorm(100)
    y <- rnorm(100)

    # Test the means, save the p-value
    #
    ps[i] <- t.test(x, y, var.equal=T)$p.value
}

hist(ps)
summary(ps)
```

When you run this, you will notice that a number of the p-values fall below $0.05$. In fact, about $5\%$ will fall below $0.05$.

It turns out that, under the null hypothesis, the p-value has a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$.

Comment: You can prove a far stronger and far-reaching statement: *no matter what the populations may be,* provided only that at least one of them is not constant, and no matter what significance level you choose, *the chance of finding a significant difference (using a t test) is always positive.*

Comment: I really appreciate both of your comments and effort in helping me out. I sincerely thank you both.

Comment: @whuber, can I ask what you meant by being not constant for a population? Also, should I understand that even if these two populations not only had the same mean but also the same standard deviation, there is still a positive chance of finding a significant difference?

Comment: @e.erhan The example I gave uses identical distributions: same mean, same standard deviation, same everything. $\text{//}$ A constant population is a population where every observation has the same value.

Comment: @Dave Thanks for the clarification!